# Are these the same?

Tags: php

In a registration form, where you can type username password and name for example, would this:

```
if (isset($username) && isset($password) && isset($firstname))
```

be the same as: `if (isset($submit))`?

Side notes: `$username = $_POST['username'];` and so on. `$submit = $_POST['submit']` - when submit button is pressed

Comment: Of course not, `submit` most likely means just that the button *submit* was pressed, not that the other fields where filled out. PS: Why didn't you just test the results and see if they where the same?

Comment: @DainisAbols because they will be the same. It doesn't matter if text fields were filled or not. Why didn't you just test and see?

Comment: @YourCommonSense He is not checking only one field, he is checking if **all** of the fields are filled out.

Comment: @DainisAbols oh no. He isn't checking if anything was *filled.*

Comment: True, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `if(isset($submit))` would only tell you if the form was submitted or not.
You should probably use `if(isset($username,$password,$firstname))`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing `$username = $_POST['username']` then `$username` will **always** be set.

Speaking of `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['submit']` - no, they aren't the same. However, in usual scenario, to check only one field is enough - so, you can roughly assume they are the same.

Comment: In usual scenario you'll have to check all post indexes. Input coming from the net or generally any input is untrusted and can be anything.